# How to link resource files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, embedded-resource

I have a strings.resx file that I've copied to another project.  It has an associated strings.designer.cs file.  The problem is that once I add them to the VS.NET project, they are separate.

In the older project, strings.designer.cs is a child of strings.resx.  If I double click strings.resx, it auto generates a  strings1.designer.cs file.

How do I recreate the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue.

After importing the resource in the new project if you look at the .csproj file you could find an `ItemGroup` section containing the `<Compile Include="string.Designer.cs" />` item, similar to the following

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    ....
    <Compile Include="string.Designer.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

So to solve your issue do the following

1. While in VisualStudio unload the project.
2. Right click on the unloaded project and select "edit {your project name}" from the context menu
3. Find the ItemGroup section containing your `<Compile Include="string.Designer.cs" />`
4. Replace

```
<Compile Include="string.Designer.cs" />
```

by

```
<Compile Include="string.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>string.resx</DependentUpon>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
</Compile>
```

Now reload the project ad you should see your files related on the solution explorer